# Connection Monitor Vs Connection Troubleshoot Vs IP Flow Verify

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

There are a whole suit of tools available to monitor networks in Azure. Of these, I am trying to understand the difference between Connection Monitor, Connection Troubleshoot and IP Flow Verify. The last two are part of Network Watcher.

To me, it seems like these are meant for the same purpose: to check if communication is allowed between a source and a destination.

What exactly are the differences between these services and in what are use cases for each?